# Redirect to a MVC action by Ajax call through ActionFilterAttribute

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a method that is called by an ajax request. Implemented a `SessionExpireFilter` inherited by `ActionFilterAttribute`. I want to redirect to another action on failed condition  in SesssionExpireFilter. My code is as below.

**Method**

```
[HttpPost]
        [SessionExpireFilter]
        public string SaveInstitute(int id, string category, string institute)
        {

            return DBMethodWeb.SaveInstitute(id, Convert.ToInt32(category), institute);

        }
```

**SessionExpireFilter**

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;

            if (HttpContext.Current.Session[SessionManagement.SchoolId] != null)
            {

            }

            else
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }));
               // HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(@"~/Home/Index");
            }




            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
```

Its rendering the page in ajax response. 
I want to redirect to an action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of redirecting at the server side, you can redirect on the client side as shown below -

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function callme(data) {
        window.location.href = data;
    }
</script>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("YourActionName", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "callme" }))
{
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Click me" />
    </div>
}
```

You ActionFilter should return a **JsonResult** as shown below -

```
public class SessionExpireFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new JsonResult() { Data = "http://www.google.com", JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

For testing purpose, I used following action -

```
[SessionExpireFilter]
public ActionResult YourActionName()
{
    return View();
}
```

At the end, my page got successfully redirected.

**NOTE:** The same example will work even if we make a JQuery AJAX request through code instead of AJAX form. All we need to do is to handle Success Function.

Comment: @developersatish, Thanks, I am glad I solved your problem. If my post helped you, please mark it answer so that it would be helpful for other guys.

Answer (score 0):

**Can you try this:**

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;

            if (HttpContext.Current.Session[SessionManagement.SchoolId] != null)
            {
            }
            else
            {
              filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
            {
                ViewName = "you path for particular view"
            };

            }
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
```

**Hope this helps..**